# VBA error when navigating with Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to download a table of proprietary investments/positions/pricing from Nationwide.  The code seems to do what I want, EXCEPT for producing an "object required" error when I attempt to select a particular account (click)

I thought I had the proper code to tell my macro to wait until IE was ready to go on, but clearly I am missing something.

In the code, the relevant line is highlighted.  If I enter a STOP above the error line, I can wait until I "see" the link appear, then "continue" the code and it runs as expected.

Because this goes to my financial accounts, I cannot provide the user name and password to allow someone to replicate the exact problem, but here is the code, and the error message and highlight.  Suggestions appreciated.

---

```
Option Explicit
'set Reference to Microsoft Internet Controls
Sub DownLoadFunds()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim sHTML
    Const sURL As String = "https://www.nationwide.com/access/web/login.htm"
    Const sURL2 As String = "https://isc.nwservicecenter.com/iApp/isc/app/ia/balanceDetail.do?basho.menuNodeId=12245"

    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Set wsTemp = Worksheets("Scratch")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True  'for debugging
    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Login:  User Name and Password "remembered" by IE
    .Document.all("submitButton").Click

    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'Select this account to show
    .Document.all("RothIRA_#########").Click  '<--Error at this line

    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .Navigate sURL2
    Do While .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .Busy = True
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set sHTML = .Document.GetElementByID("fundByFundOnly")
    With wsTemp
        .Cells.Clear
        .Range("a2") = sHTML.innertext
    End With
    .Quit
End With
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

This is the error message:

[image: Error Message]

This shows the highlighted line:
[image: Line for error]

**EDIT:**

At Tim Williams suggestion, I added a loop to test for the presence of the desired element.  This seems to work:

---

```
...
On Error Resume Next
    Do
        Err.Clear
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait (Time + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
        .Document.getelementbyid("RothIRA_#########").Click
    Loop Until Err.Number = 0
On Error GoTo 0
```

### ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible/likely that the page is using script to dynamically load some content or generate some layout *after* your "wait" loop has finished. That loop only waits until all linked content/resources have been loaded - it does not wait for scripts on the loaded page to finish, etc.

One approach is to loop your code waiting for the desired element to be rendered:

```
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC as Long  = 5 'limit on how long to wait...
Dim t
t = Timer
Do While .Document.all("RothIRA_#########") Is Nothing
    DoEvents
    'or you can Sleep here
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC  Then Exit Do 
Loop
'carry on...
```

Comment: Yes it seems a loop waiting for the desired element to load is what is required.  Your suggestion, when I first tried it, resulted in an error message.  So I took to checking, within a loop including `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT`, for the presence of the desired element.

Answer (score 1):

`IE.Document.all("#RothIRA_....")` is returning `Nothing` (`null` in more refined languages), so calling the `Click` method is causing the error.

Your code is the same as doing this:

```
Dim rothElement As Whatever
rothElement = IE.Document.all("#RothIRA_....")
rothElement.Click
```

...when you should do this:

```
Dim rothElement As Whatever
rothElement = IE.Document.all("#RothIRA_....")
If rothElement <> Nothing Then
    rothElement.Click
End If
```

I suggest using the modern `document.GetElementById` method instead of the deprecated (if not obsolete) `document.All` API.

Comment: The problem remains the signal that the desired element is present on the page.  Should I just loop until rothElement <> Nothing?  Or is there something more elegant?

Comment: Also, using .Document.getelementbyid("RothIRA_#########").Click causes the same "object required" error problem.  But thanks for letting me know my original syntax has been deprecated.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you should ensure that the `id=""` attribute of the document is correct.

Comment: ID is correct.  The problem, as I mentioned in my question, is that part of the page hasn't yet loaded at the time the command is executed.  But Tim Williams has provided an approach that works.  Thanks.